# Using a paged list on model first approach?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, paging, pagedlist

I would like to page the data in my view using a paged list , I did this previously using a web grid but am finding it difficult to do this using the model first approach.Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Steve Sanderson describes an example of pagination support in his book [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1430234040/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d3_g14_i2?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1WRCGYDDA0J3Z2NRTV8V&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294) which I highly recommend (although it shouldn't be long until the next [version](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1430242361/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_g14_i2?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=03VRFB6QMV2ZZ8Q4TDC5&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294) is released).

He describes a product controller (listing pages of products) as:

```
public class ProductController : Controller {
   public int PageSize = 4; //This could be retrieved from the database

   private IProductRepository repository;
   public ProductController(IProductRepository repoParam) {
      repository = repoParam;
   }

   public ViewResult List(int page = 1) {
      ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel {
         Products = repository.Products
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
         PagingInfo = new PagingInfo {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
         }
      };
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

A query to the action may then be in the form:

```
http://localhost:23081/Product/List?page=2
```

(or whatever routing you require).

This view model would then be:

```
public class ProductsListViewModel {
   public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
   public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And the PagingInfo model would be:

```
public class PagingInfo {
   public int TotalItems { get; set; }
   public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
   public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
   public int TotalPages {
      get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
   }
}
```

You can then use this paging information to display the information in your view as required.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my PagedList nuget package on github:

https://github.com/troygoode/pagedlist

This will allow you to write code like so:

*MyController.cs*

```
public class MyController : Controller{
  public object MyRoute(){
    var pagedProducts = ProductsRepo.All().ToPagedList();
    return View(pagedProducts);
  }
}
```

*MyRoute.cshtml*

```
<ul>
  @foreach(var product in ViewModel){
    <li>@product.Name</li>
  }
</ul>
@Html.PagedListPager(ViewModel, page=> Url.Action("MyRoute", {page = page}))
```